# How to call JSP page in Android

Tags: java, android, jsp

I'm implementing JSP page in my Android application. I don't know how to use JSP Url in Android. I tried and run the application. But the page is blank does not show any info in Android layout and also in log cat. Here is my code.

```
public class JSP_Activity extends Activity
{
    public static  String strUrl=null;
    String strText = null;

    public void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.jsp_page);
        connectWithGet_JspPage();
    }


    private void connectWithGet_JspPage()
    {
        class GetJspPage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
        {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... strUrls) 
            {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                strUrl="http://test.window2india.com/mobile/home.jsp";
                Log.e("strUrl :=","" + strUrl);
                String strOutPut = null;

                    strOutPut=getOutPutFromUrl(strUrl);
                    Log.e("strOutPut :="," "+strOutPut);
                    return strOutPut.toString();

            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String output1) 
            {
                //outputText.setText(output1);
                Log.e("strOutPut :="," "+output1);
            }

        }
        GetJspPage getJspPageAsyncTask = new GetJspPage();
        getJspPageAsyncTask.execute();
    }



    private String getOutPutFromUrl(String url)
        {

         StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer("");
         try 
         {
             InputStream stream = getHttpConnection(url);
             BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
             String s = "";
             while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                 output.append(s);
         } 
         catch (IOException e1) 
         {
             e1.printStackTrace();
         }
         return output.toString();

    }



     private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
             throws IOException 
      {
         InputStream stream = null;
         URL url = new URL(urlString);
         URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

         try 

         {
             HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
             httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
             httpConnection.connect();

             if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) 
             {
                 stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
             }
         } 

         catch (Exception ex) 
         {
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }
         return stream;
     }



}
```

Comment: The backing technology of an HTTP URL isn't relevant.

Comment: use [webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: use webview component to load jsp page like webview.loadurl("url.jsp");

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,it will help for display the content send by the jsp.This code is useful for normal layout not for webview.You have to parse the content and display in your custom layout.

```
      new Thread(new Runnable() 
            {
                    public void run() 
                    {  
          try
           {

            URL url = new URL("http://test.window2india.com/mobile/home.jsp");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
             BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
             String x = "";
             String total = "";
             int i=0;
             ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList();
             while((x = r.readLine()) != null)
             {
                         content.add(x);

             }
             in.close();
             r.close();
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();

         }

    }

            }).start();
```

Comment: You should explain your answer

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ We can display the content send by jsp.

Comment: Not to me. You should explain the answers you provide here on SO, not just say _"Try this:"_ followed by a bunch of code. It doesn't need to be a long explanation, maybe a line or two.

Comment: "http://test.window2india.com/mobile/home.jsp" this my url which is i created in JSP format i want to call this page as it is on my application.So i don't how to do it ? This is my first time I'm trying to implement JSP with Android.

Comment: @tazeenmulani if you want to display the like web page in your android device means you have to do it in webview and load your url.